# How to access the NN layers in a class in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, class, layer

I have been training a NN which is written in Tensorflow 1.4 and everything works well.
But now, I want to save the NN structure (weights) to not train every time that I want to get the variable OUT. So, I guess that I need to be able to access the layers, I know it's pretty simple when using Keras `model` (with functions like  `model.summary()`  `model.save_weights()`).

Any ideas how could I save the NN layers to save **out**, and not to train everytime.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MODEL:


    def __init__(self):
        self.__build_flag = -1
        self.__train_flag = -1



    def __NN(self, x):
        with tf.variable_scope("Residual"):
            for j in range(self.__num_layers):
                layer_name = "Layer_"+str(j)
                with tf.variable_scope(layer_name):
                    W = tf.get_variable(name="weights", shape=(hdim,hdim),
                                        dtype=tf.float64)
                    b = tf.get_variable(name="biases", shape=(hdim),
                                        dtype=tf.float64)
                    if j==0: # first layer
                        res_out = res_in + self.__tf_nlr(
                            tf.matmul(res_in, W) + b)
                    else: # subsequent layers
                        res_out = res_out + self.__tf_nlr(
                            tf.matmul(res_out, W) + b)
        with tf.variable_scope("Output_projection",
                            initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(
                            maxval=std, minval=-std)):
            W = tf.get_variable(name="weights", shape=(hdim, ddim),
                            dtype=tf.float64)
            b = tf.get_variable(name="biases", shape=(ddim),
                            dtype=tf.float64)
            out = tf.matmul(res_out, W) + b

        return out
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Set your trainable variables (weights, biases) as an instance attribute (i.e. self.weights = W after you initialize W and likewise for b). Since instance attributes are accessible across your entire class, you can write a function (name it 'save_model()' or 'load_model()') that just returns self.W, self.b, and any other information relating to your model.

Comment: Hello again, I have not managed to solve this problem. I hope that you can still help me. I have saved the weights and the biases, as you said, and now it looks like: ```    ....     
          out = tf.matmul(res_out, W) + b

            self.weights = W
            self.b = b
            self.out=out
```